# dynamic content after fn.readfile for an email

Tags: node.js

I'm sending an email for user confirmation with `AWS SES` from a custom file.

Is there any way to include custom params after `fs.readFile()`?

(For example, a variable with a dynamic URL for an activation code.)

```
fs.readFile('./mypath', function (err, email) {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  // some modifications to email response
  ses.sendEmail(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    return; // all ok
)}
```

I'm looking for another option instead of reading the entire file and replacing the desired content. In PHP, for example, defining variables before `file_get_contents()` does the trick if the variable is defined inside the document. So I was looking for something like that.

Comment: Where do you want to include the params? In the file that you read? Modify the content that you get and that's it?

Comment: I was wondering for another option than reading the entire file and replacing the desired content.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It's not clear what you are trying to do and why reading the file is not good for you

Comment: in php, for example, defining variables before `file_get_contents()` do the trick if the variable is defined inside the document. So I was looking for the same.

Comment: Defining variable for what? What do you want to do with that variable?

Comment: a variable with a dynamic URL for an activation code, for example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126119/discussion-between-devstarlight-and-vsevolod-goloviznin).